# PrimeFaces Lightbox effect not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
<p:lightBox iframe="true" widgetVar="dlg">
    <h:outputLink value="apply.flow" title="Apply">
        <p:commandButton value="Start" />
    </h:outputLink>
</p:lightBox>
```

The windows comes up as expected and works well.  However the lightbox effect is not being displayed (the screen is not darkening as it does on the PrimeFaces demo website).  I've tried several browsers so that's not an issue and there are no JS errors being thrown.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

cheers,

--Stu

Comment: Hmm works fine with me. Are you overriding the css anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for checking.  We inherited a 6000 line css file, so that is a very strong possibility.  I was hoping to never have to open it ;)

Comment: Firebug is your friend!

Comment: you must have overridden some css somewhere with `modal` or `opacity` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments / pointers on this.  Using Firebug I managed to find the offending override for the `opacity` of the overlay and fixed the issue.